# Identification Code (Python3)

Tags: python, arrays, input, while-loop

Identification Code is like GYYMMDD.
G is 1 or 2 which means male or female.
And YYMMDD is Birthday.

I've just written like this :

```
s=[]
while True:
  while True:
        s = input('Enter 7 numbers : ')
        if len(s) == 7:
            break
        else:
            print('Retype your 7 personal numbers!!')
  if '0' < s[1] < '3':
    break
  else:
    print('retry')
```

However, I have no idea to input Birthdaycode into array.

Please enlighten me on the specifics.

Comment: There is no [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) in your code. That's a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq),

Comment: Okay. I was confused list and array. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The following will put the YY, MM, DD into a single array:

```
>>> input_ = "1851803"
>>> birthdarray = [input_[i:i+2] for i in range(1, 6, 2)]
>>> birthdarray = ['85', '18', '03']
```

It's evident that you're new to python/programming. However in general, it would be best to start to use functions to verify your input and either accept or reject the user's input; instead of doing it all within  while loops.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and yes, just started to learn from this month. Okay, I write separately.